# Raphaeljs graphics not rendering in multiple bootstrap tabs

Tags: javascript, html, raphael

I've been coding on a human body app that gets input from patients about which parts hurts him/her as part of medical tests, for this I created an image map using raphaeljs vector library.

[image]

I have to show two skeleton images in two bootstrap tabs, one in each tab with their circle placeholders so the user can click on them to select the pain or swelling areas.

[image][image]

1. To get pain areas in tab 1 I start by adding a png skeleton image as the content of my first boostrap tab.
2. I draw yellow circles to be the placeholders for pain and swelling parts.
3. I have to do the same for tab 2, this time I have to show the same skeleton png but with different name, for instance I copy the same code for tab 1 for the png image and placeholders as well.

The problem is that the yellow circles are not rendering in the second tab (swelling or 'Inflamación'), instead they do in the first one (pain or 'Dolor'), I realize of that because in the first tab the circles are overlapped as I show in the next image.

[image]

By what I see, the Raphael lib cannot put the second tab circles coords on a hidden section, instead these coords are put in the first tab. That's why I get this behavior.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.
This is my code..

```js
var style= {id: 'skeleton'+1, opacity: '0.65', fill: '#FEEA3E', 'stroke-width': '0','stroke-opacity': '1'};
    
var skel = Raphael("skeleton", 150, 352);
skel.image("<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/maps/skeleton.png", 0, 0, 150, 352);
/* ======PAIN=========
Draw skeleton for pain*/
// Skeleton script 
var shapes= new Array();
var circles_body = new Array({xc: 27.5, yc: 76, r: 10}, {xc: 100.5, yc: 76, r: 10}, {xc: 12, yc: 132, r: 10}, {xc: 110, yc: 132, r: 10}, {xc: 10.5, yc: 178, r: 10}, {xc: 125, yc: 175.5, r: 10}, {xc: 51, yc: 253, r: 10}, {xc: 72, yc: 253, r: 9});
for (var i = 0; i < circles_body.length; i++) {
shapes[i]= skel.circle(circles_body[i].xc, circles_body[i].yc, circles_body[i].r);
shapes[i].attr(style);
shapes[i].id= "skeleton"+i;
shapes[i].click(function(){
if(this.attr('fill')== "#990000"){
pj--;
this.animate({fill: "#FEEA3E"}, 200);
}else{
pj++;
this.animate({fill: "#990000"}, 200);
}
});
};

    /* ====== SWELLING =========
Draw skeleton for swelling*/
// Skeleton script 
var shapes= new Array();
var circles_body_i = new Array({xc: 27.5, yc: 76, r: 10}, {xc: 100.5, yc: 76, r: 10}, {xc: 12, yc: 132, r: 10}, {xc: 110, yc: 132, r: 10}, {xc: 10.5, yc: 178, r: 10}, {xc: 125, yc: 175.5, r: 10}, {xc: 51, yc: 253, r: 10}, {xc: 72, yc: 253, r: 9});
for (var i = 0; i < circles_body_i.length; i++) {
shapes[i]= skel.circle(circles_body_i[i].xc, circles_body_i[i].yc, circles_body_i[i].r);
shapes[i].attr(style);
shapes[i].id= "skeleton_i"+i;
shapes[i].click(function(){
  if(this.attr('fill')== "#990000"){
    pj--;
    this.animate({fill: "#FEEA3E"}, 200);
  }else{
    pj++;
    this.animate({fill: "#990000"}, 200);
  }
});
};
```

```html
   <section role="tabpanel">
        <ul id="examTab" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
          <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#dolor" id="dolor-tab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="dolor" aria-expanded="true">Dolor</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#infl" role="tab" id="infl-tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="infl" aria-expanded="false">Inflamación</a></li>
    ..
    </section>    
 <article role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade active in" id="dolor" aria-labelledby="dolor-tab">
       <h3>1) Dolor</h3>
        <h4 class="break-one">Seleccione dónde está el dolor</h4>
        <figure class="break-two">
          <article id="skeleton"></article>
          <figcaption><em>Cuerpo en general</em></figcaption>
        </figure>
    </article>
 ..
 <article role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="infl" aria-labelledby="infl-tab">
        <h3>2) Inflamación</h3>
        <h4 class="break-one">Seleccione dónde las inflamaciones</h4 class="break-one">
        <figure class="break-two">
          <article id="skeleton_inf_i"></article>
          <figcaption><em>Cuerpo en general</em></figcaption>
        </figure>
    </article>
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad,
I was adding all the circles to a same skeleton object (skel)

```
/* ======PAIN=========
Draw skeleton for pain*/
...
shapes[i]= skel.circle(circles_body[i].xc, circles_body[i].yc, circles_body[i].r);
```

...

and then the other skeleton

```
/* ====== SWELLING =========
 Draw skeleton for swelling*/
    ...   
shapes[i]= skel.circle(circles_body_i[i].xc, circles_body_i[i].yc, circles_body_i[i].r);    
    ...
```